# Exporting to PDF in Illustrator: Reduce file size in document with multiple occurrences of the same raster graphic

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, file-size, save

I have a multi-page PDF created with 7 Artboards in Adobe Illustrator CS6.
The problem is the PDF file created is too large (40MB).

The pages (artboards) have the same exact high-res raster graphic as a background, but with different vector graphics on top of them. I'm sure the PDF file size could be smaller if Illustrator didn't include that raster 7 times, but only ONCE and referenced it.

Can this be accomplished somehow? Forcing Illustrator to not write the same raster data to file 7 times, but only once...

P.S. I'd like to keep it one single PDF file for easy distribution. Exporting an SVG + PNG folder wouldn't be a satisfactory solution, but if there's no other way, let me know.

Comment: Also: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46153/adobe-pdf-file-too-big-to-upload-what-are-my-options/54948#54948

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you are just pasting the graphic into the document. There are a few alternate methods to reduce the filesize:

### Option 1: Use File → Place...

Instead of pasting the raster image into your document, use **File** → ***Place...***. This will create linked files in your document:

[image: Illustrator screenshot]

It's important to note that your .ai file will no longer be self-contained. If you delete, move, or rename the source image, Illustrator will not be able to find it. *This will **not** matter for the exported PDF.*

[image: Illustrator error]

### Option 2: Use Symbols

Instead of placing the images, you could use **Symbols**. Just create a Symbol of the raster artwork, then drag it into the document as many times as needed:

[image: Illustrator screenshot of symbols]

### Option 3: Print the PDF

If you have Adobe Acrobat (or some other sufficient PDF printer), you can print the PDF.

[image: print dialog]

1. **File** → ***Print...***
2. Select **Adobe PDF** as the Printer
3. ***Print***

This is the most efficient method and is okay for proofing. If the file is just being passed around to be viewed on a screen, this is usually fine. However, **do not use this type of file for printing**. All sorts of compression and nasty things happen when you print as a PDF.

### The Results

Using my [2.78 MB example file](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mars_/9966719103/in/pool-publicdomain), here are the results of the methods I just outlined:

- Copy and pasting: 46.1 MB
- Placing: 7.84 MB
- Symbol: 18.6 MB
- PDF Print: 139 KB

Note: These are all using the Illustrator Default PDF saving options. You could get better results by selecting another preset or modifying the settings yourself.

[image: Save as PDF dialog]

For example, the copy and pasting method saved with the [Smallest File Size] preset output for me as 150 KB which is comparable to the PDF print method.

### Summary:

- File → Place: Low PDF file size, but the source .ai will not be self containing.
- Symbols: Source .ai file will be self containing, but PDF file size will not be as low
- Print as PDF (or use Smallest File Size preset): PDF file size will be extremely small, but the resulting file is not sufficient for print